# asp.net mvc 3 razor user uploads a file and the files is automatically being sent to specified email

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, razor

Is there a way to create a page where user will be able to upload a file and the time he click upload that file will automatically be sent to specified email?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. :) research file uploads in razor and sending email via the system.net namespace. If you have a specific issue let us know.